# No space left on /root, after deleting process that lsof told me was utilizing it

Tags: linux

I am trying to install a software and got the disk space error. I have tried removing around 30G, still the /dev/sda2 is showing its full. Though it is not as shown in the available memory on the disk as below.

```
[rav@E~]$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       960G  649G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        8.4G     0  8.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           8.4G  156k  8.4G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           8.4G   52M  8.4G   1% /run
tmpfs           8.4G     0  8.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1       985G  456G  480G  49% /recovery
tmpfs           8.4G   66k  8.4G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1       475M  343M  104M  77% /boot
tmpfs           1.7G  8.2k  1.7G   1% /run/user/1010
tmpfs           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /run/user/1001
[rav@E ~]$

[rav@E ~]$ df -i -h
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2         57M   18M   40M   31% /
devtmpfs         2.0M   464  2.0M    1% /dev
tmpfs            2.0M     9  2.0M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            2.0M   700  2.0M    1% /run
tmpfs            2.0M    13  2.0M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1         59M  9.7M   49M   17% /recovery
tmpfs            2.0M    25  2.0M    1% /tmp
/dev/sda1        120K   425  119K    1% /boot
tmpfs            2.0M    22  2.0M    1% /run/user/1010
tmpfs            2.0M     1  2.0M    1% /run/user/1001
```

I killed some of the process that were using the deleted files by seraching through the lsof command, but in vain.

Comment: /dev/sdb1       985G  456G  480G  49% /recovery

Comment: I have less space in / that is mounted on /dev/sda2

Comment: I have made the title in to a coherent sentence, please check that it is what you meant.

Comment: You have no space left, files won't be deleted if they are open or have a file-name.

Comment: What do you mean by “Though it is not as shown in the available memory on the disk as below.”?

Comment: What @ctrl-alt-delor said: the disk space used by a given file isn't marked as free if there is a process using that file, even if you've rm'd the file. The space is only reclaimed when the process with the open filehandle closes the filehandle (or ends, which has the same effect)

Answer (score -2):

```
tune2fs -m 30 /dev/sda2
```

made the wonders

Comment: How did reserving 30% of the filesystem for root instead of the usual 5% help?

Comment: It helps users from not consuming the left over space, so the admin can extend it when needed while he runs out of space during an installation of software.

Comment: But you're already out of space, so what leftover space is that?